# 595 Shift Register Not Working Properly

Tags: led, shift-register

I followed the tutorial on controlling 8 LEDs using a SIPO SN74HC595N shift register on both [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-4-eight-leds/overview) and [Last Minute Engineer](https://lastminuteengineers.com/74hc595-shift-register-arduino-tutorial/). I used a Sparkfun Pro Micro (Arduino Leonardo equivalent).

The problem is the LEDs are not lighting up in the way that I'm expecting it do it. Both guides said each LED will light up one after another. After all 8 are lit, all of them will turn off. [Here is my result](https://gph.is/g/Z2mPdPW). Other LEDs will either dim up or down as the target LED turn on. I used the code provided from the guide and only changed the pinout number. The resistor values are the same for each color so it can't be the resistor. Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

```
/*
Test code for 74HC595N SIPO shift register. Used with Pro Micro
*/

int latchPin = 16;
int clockPin = 15;
int dataPin = 14;
int outputEnablePin = 10;

byte leds = 0;    // Variable to hold the pattern of which LEDs are currently turned on or off

void setup() 
{
  // Set all the pins of 74HC595 as OUTPUT
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(outputEnablePin, OUTPUT);
  outputEnablePin = LOW;
}

/*
 * loop() - this function runs over and over again
 */
void loop() 
{
  leds = 0; // Initially turns all the LEDs off, by giving the variable 'leds' the value 0
  updateShiftRegister();
  delay(500);
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) // Turn all the LEDs ON one by one.
  {
    bitSet(leds, i);    // Set the bit that controls that LED in the variable 'leds'
    updateShiftRegister();
    delay(500);
  }
}

/*
 * updateShiftRegister() - This function sets the latchPin to low, then calls the Arduino function 'shiftOut' to shift out contents of variable 'leds' in the shift register before putting the 'latchPin' high again.
 */
void updateShiftRegister()
{
   digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
   shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, leds);
   digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
}
```

**Schematics:**

[image]

Comment: `The resistor values are the same for each color so it can't be the resistor.` What makes you think that? The current through the LED is dictated by the resistor value and the LED's forward voltage. The LED's forward voltage is dictated by the colour. Thus you need to size the resistor correctly for each colour of LED.

Comment: That said, the fact that some turn part way on when they shouldn't really is a concern.

Comment: Is your pro micro a 3.3V or a 5V one?

Comment: The Pro Micro is 5V. What I meant by the resistors is there is two led of the same color and there is 4 different colors. I calculate the resistors value based on their given forward voltage and current for each color. The resistor value is the same for the pair of leds with the same color.

Comment: It would really help if you add a schematic of how you actually built the circuit, instead of me trying to debug your circuit from a low resolution, animated GIF. Your code looks fine at first glance, btw.

Comment: The GND of the 74HC595 is connected to the right power rail (blue line) on your breadboard. But this rail **isn't connect** to the GND of the Arduino.

Comment: I was making the schematic for StarCat and just found that GND error! Stupid me! I connected it to ground and now the dimming LEDs are gone! However, I still have problems with the LED. The LEDs are not lighting up in the pattern that the code designed them to.

Comment: @Agriculex, Glad to be of help ;-) You could write an answer to your own question.

Comment: I just found out solution to the pattern issue. The guides didn't say it (at least not clearly enough) that pin 10 (SRCLR with the line/bar on top) needs to be connected to 5V.

Comment: @Agriculex - Please answer your own question then accept that answer in 48 hours.

Comment: StackExchange is *not* a forum. You don't edit the question's title with "Solved" if you have an answer. Instead you write an answer and (later, when you're allowed to) you mark it. Please correct that. People coming here don't look for "Solved", they look for marked answers.

Comment: Did that just now. I'm still new to how StackExchange works opps.

Answer (score 1):

The dimming problem was found to be the shift register IC not connected to Ground (dumb me).

However, there is still problem with LED's on and off pattern. Sometimes two LEDs turn on at the same time and all previous LEDS turning off before the last or second last LED is turned on. It turns out Pin 10 (SRCLR Bar) needs to be pulled to high to solve that pattern discrepancy.

Comment: Yes. You can't leave important pins, like SRCLR, floating. Signals that matter must be intentionally set. True with any chip.